# VB.Net - Entry in datagridview keeps duplicating on event

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagrid

Here is my code, everytime I click the Button1, instead of refreshing the Datagridview, it only adds another entry that is a duplicate of the previous one. I know I'm missing something in my code that will clear the data in Datagrid before loading it again. Please help..

```
Private Function LoadData_UnitProcess()

    Dim UP_SQL As String = "SELECT LotNum FROM Transactions WHERE StatusID=3 ORDER BY Process_EntryDate DESC"
    Dim UP_Ad As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(UP_SQL, strCon)


    UP_Ad.Fill(UP_Ds, "Transactions")
    UnitOnProcess_DG.DataSource = UP_Ds.Tables(0)

    With UnitOnProcess_DG
        .RowHeadersVisible = False
        .Columns(0).HeaderCell.Value = "Lot #"
        .Columns(0).Width = "363"
        .AllowUserToAddRows = False
    End With


    LoadData_UnitProcess = ""
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    LoadData_UnitProcess()
End Sub

Private Sub Displayer_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    LoadData_UnitProcess()
End Sub
```

Comment: 1) Your `LoadData_UnitReady` is a sub and not a function: It doesn't retun anything. 2) no one of the showed sub call the function. Both call something else

Comment: @genespos, `LoadData_UnitReady` actually is a function but a poorly written one. Firstly, the return type isn't specified. Secondly, it uses the old VB6-style of returning a value by assigning to the function name. Most importantly though, there's no good reason for it to be a function because it always returns an empty string and that value has absolutely nothing to do with the purpose of the method.  It SHOULD be a `Sub`.

Comment: Sorry about that, I copied the wrong function. I edited it now.

Comment: I understand what you mean sir genespos and sir @jmcilhinney, Mind giving me a suggestion on how to do it right? Cos I'm new in vb.net. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dataset UP_Ds is probably a property or  field. You need to reset the dataset before filling it again, otherwise the content is appended to the previous.

```
UP_Ds.Reset()
UP_Ad.Fill(UP_Ds, "Transactions")
UnitOnProcess_DG.DataSource = UP_Ds.Tables(0)
```

Comment: Whoa! Thank you so much sir. Works like a charm!